# Manipulate and Aggregate table columns in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

Hi I want to do SQL Presto query for the data table (say **user_data**) looks like

```
user | Col 1 | Col 2 |  Col 3
-----------------------------
 A   |    b  | 2     | T
 B   |    a  | 2     | F
 A   |    c  | 3     | F
 B   |    d  | 4     | T
 A   |    d  | 2     | T
```

With this data table, I would like to generate the following output.

**Output:** Aggregate columns for each distinct user **whiling preserving the order of column values**

```
user | Col 1  | Col 2  |  Col 3
--------------------------------
 A   | (b,c,d)| (2,3,2)| (T,F,T)
 B   |  (a,d) | (2,4)  | (F,T)
```

Thanks in advance!

I think it should be using GROUP BY but not sure how to use it. Thank you!

Comment: Table data is not ordered. So, row A|b|2|T does neither come before nor after row A|c|3|F. But you can of course decide for an order the data shall get selected by. Do you want a user's data ordered by col_1? Then what data type is (b,c,d) supposed to be? A string? An array?

Comment: You need to explicitly specify ordering. While the source data can be in some order - Presto is processing data in parallel (for obvious reasons) so no stable order is guaranteed.

Comment: I need an order of any one of the columns. Let's say if I want to order the table based on col 1 values. I can prepare the table with ORDER BY Col 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_agg](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html), but you need to defined the order of the elements. For example in your `user_data` table you need a column like autogenerated `id` or `date` of creation or modification to be used in order to guarantee the data is ordered in an unique way.

```
SELECT user
      ,array_agg(Col1 ORDER BY Col1) as Col1
      ,array_agg(Col2 ORDER BY Col1) as Col2
      ,array_agg(Col3 ORDER BY Col1) as Col3
FROM user_data
GROUP BY user;
```

Comment: Is there any easy way to create the "id"? Or what if I want the table to be ordered based on the values in Col 1?

Comment: Then just used the Col 1 in the order by clause.